# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'. I have installed crypto but still the same error

Tags: python, flask, pycrypto

I am having the following error:

```
    from Crypto.Random import random
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'
```

I have installed Crypto and pycryptodome but still get the same error. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please add the command you used to install Crypto and pycryptodome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows filesystem is case-insensitive so crypto and Crypto are effectively considered the same thing. When you subsequently install `pycryptodome`, `pip` finds that a directory named with the target namespace already exists , follow these;

```
pip uninstall crypto
```

Go to this path and delete the crypto folder;

```
/path/to/python/Lib/site-packages/
```

Uninstall pycryptodome if it exists, and install again;

```
pip uninstall pycryptodome
pip install pycryptodome
```

Check this path again after installation, rename Folder "crypto" to "Crypto";

```
/path/to/python/Lib/site-packages/
```

Comment: Wonderful. Helped me after few hours of searching for solution.